# Can't connect to service when using consul for service discovery | Node.js

Tags: node.js, axios, microservices, consul, api-gateway

I am working on creating an API gateway and so far I can manage to get everything to work for single instances where I hard code the IP and port of the server I want my API gateway to connect to.

I have seen few examples of how to accomplish service discovery with Consul/Node.js.

I did find this one and I have tried to make it work but I can't get the watcher to work right and pass me the IP:port combo I need to connect to the service.

All of the below files are just parts and not the whole thing. The important parts are there though.

**This is my app.js file**

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    const CONSUL_ID = require('uuid').v4();
    const ip = require('ip');
    const my_IP = ip.address();
    let options = {
      name: 'api-gateway',
      address: `${my_IP}`,
      port: 8080,
      id: CONSUL_ID,
      check: {
        ttl: '10s',
        deregister_critical_service_after: '1m'
      }
    };
    consul.agent.service.register(options, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`Registered service with ID of ${CONSUL_ID}`);
    });

    setInterval(() => {
      consul.agent.check.pass({id:`service:${CONSUL_ID}`}, err => {
        if (err) throw new Error(err);
      });
    }, 5 * 1000);

    process.on('SIGINT', () => {
      console.log(`SIGINT. De-Registering service with ID of ${CONSUL_ID}`);
      consul.agent.service.deregister(CONSUL_ID, (err) => {
        if(err) console.log(`Error de-registering service from consul, with error of : ${err}`);
        if(!err) console.log(`De-registered service with ID of ${CONSUL_ID}`);
        process.exit();
      });
    });
    console.log(`API gateway server running express started on port ${port}.`);
});
```

I have two other test services running that the only difference between my app.js above and these test ones are that they have `name: 'test-service',` for the service name.

**This is my routes file**

```
var consul = require("consul")({host: '10.0.1.248'});
var known_data_instances = [];
const apiAdapter = require('./apiAdapter')


// Keep a list of healthy services
var watcher = consul.watch({
  method: consul.health.service,
  options: {
    service:'test-service',
    passing:true
  }
});



watcher.on('change', data => {
  console.log('received discovery update:', data.length);
  known_data_instances = [];

  data.forEach(entry => {
    known_data_instances.push(`http://${entry.Service.Address}:${entry.Service.Port}/`);
  });
});

watcher.on('error', err => {
  console.error('watch error', err);
});

const BASE_URL = known_data_instances[Math.floor(Math.random()*known_data_instances.length)];
// const api = apiAdapter(BASE_URL + ':8081');
const api = apiAdapter(BASE_URL);



// router.get('/login', isAuthorized, (req, res) => {
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  api.get(req.path).then(resp => {
    res.send(resp.data);
  });
});
```

**API adapter file**

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = (baseURL) => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
  });
};
```

I am expecting to be able to send a request using axios to a HTTP endpoint on a different service on a different server when getting the IP and port from consul.

Actual result is:

```
(node:3230) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
```

Seems to me like it is not picking up the URLs and is defaulting back onto localhost port 80.

I'm a bit lost on all of this since I have never build an application with consul and while the consul.io docs are great, there just isn't much of a guide base online for making this easy to learn.

Guess the question comes down to, how do I get my api adapter to make requests to my different services, in this case `test-service`?

Comment: any luck? were you able to solve this?